# Theta functions approximations

Tags: calculus

Could you explain the following aproximations give more than 40 decimal

$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } e^{-k^2}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\left(2 e^{-4 \pi ^2} \left(1+e^{3 \pi ^2}\right)+1\right) \sqrt{\pi }-1\right)$$

Comment: You're asking why $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-k^2}\approx \sum_{k=-2}^{2} e^{-k^2\pi^2}$$. Can you think of an  identity that establishes that?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30804/proving-the-identity-sum-n-infty-infty-e-pi-n2x-x-1-2-sum-n-in) is what you're looking for.