# Is the solution to $\frac{e^n}{n} = e^2$ related to $\pi$?

Tags: exponential-function, approximation, pi

I learned recently that the solution to $\frac{e^n}{n}=e^2$ is 3.146.., which is very near $\pi$. Is this just a coincidence, or is there something to the expression that leads to it being so close to $\pi$?

I feel like my question might be related to this, but I'm not too sure how to relate the two:
[Curious relation between $e$ and $\pi$ that produces almost integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072897/curious-relation-between-e-and-pi-that-produces-almost-integers?rq=1)

Comment: You'll find that $e$ and $\pi$ have a lot of properties that make people believe they're related. There's even a question about interesting relations between them.

Comment: Not really an explanation, but $$\pi-\ln(\pi)\approx 2$$ implies the observation.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo What is that question? It might help find the answer.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, that may be helpful

Comment: BenThayer and @Peter $\frac{259}{100}-\log_5\left(\frac{259}{100}\right)\approx 2$. Is the solution to $\frac{5^n}{n}=5^2$ related to $\frac{259}{100}$? (Note that the solution to $\frac{5^n}{n}=5^2$ is 2.591..., which is very near $\frac{259}{100}$).

Comment: @Pedro Nice, but what has that to do with the solution for $e$ instead of $5$ ? In other words, how did you get the $2.59$ ?

Comment: @Peter The point is that I didn't understand what is special about the numbers $e$ and $\pi$ in the question and in your reasoning (because there are other numbers with the same properties, for example, $5$ and $\frac{259}{100}$). Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Pedro I never claimed that my approximation is an explanation. It is just another way to understand the observation. Therefore the formulation "Not really..."

Comment: @Peter I have found also a other solution

Answer (score 2):

$3.146$ is not very near $\pi$. There are million expressions as close. $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$, $\dfrac{22}7$, or $\sqrt{31}$ for example. This means nothing. We would be more surprised by a match on the first twenty decimals.

Try this: http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standard

In any case, close values do not mean that there is a deeper meaning. I find it more intriguing to see $\pi$ appear a the constant in Stirling's asymptotic formula for the factorial ($\sqrt{2\pi}$), though the numerical value is different.

Answer (score 0):

*(A proof and explanation based on the comments)*

Let $\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{p>0 \land p\neq1}$, $q$ be 'know' and $x$ -unknow:
$$
\frac{p^x}{x}=p^q\implies x\neq0
$$
$$
p^{x-q}=x
$$
From: $a^c=b \iff log_ab=c$

We get
$$
log_px=x-q \implies \bbox[5px,border:2px solid green]{q=x-log_px }\leftarrow comments
$$
Because of the logarithm $log_px \Rightarrow\bbox[5px,border:2px solid yellow]{x>0}$

**Conclusion**:

> $$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid blue]{log_px= x-q}\iff\bbox[5px,border:2px solid blue]{q+log_px=x}\iff \bbox[5px,border:2px solid cyan]{p^{x-q}=x}$$$$
> x;p>0 \land p\neq1$$

---

EDIT: 
We can also say:$q+log_px=p^{x-q}$

When $q=0$ $\implies \exists!x:log_px=p^x$

I) For $ a\in(0;1) $ $\implies \exists!x:q+log_px=p^{x-q}$

[image]

We just transform $a^x\rightarrow p^{x-q}$ $\land$ $log_ax\rightarrow q+log_px$

II) For $a>1$:

[image]

- $q>0$ $\rightarrow$ $2$ solutions
- $q<0$ $\rightarrow$ $0$ solutions

---

I think $x$ can be found at least via ***numerical analysis***

or *via **a graph***-sample pair functions: 
$$f_1(x)=log_px\land g_1(x)=x-q$$
$$f_2(x)=p^{x-q}\land g_2(x)=x$$

in ***the points of intersection***.

For the $(p;q)$ pairs:

1)$(e;2)\mapsto x\approx\pi$ @Peter

2)$(5;2)\mapsto x\cong2.59$ @Pedro

I am gonna find the other solutions:

I. $x=e^{x-2}$
[image]
$x_1\approx\frac{1}{2\pi+\frac{e}{122.39}}$ and $x_2\approx\pi$

II. $x=5^{x-2}$
[image]
$x_1\approx \frac{1}{0.973+10\sqrt{5}}$ and $x_2\approx2.591708$

---

Properties:

I.

> For the pair $(p;1)$ at $x=1\rightarrow p$ can be everything from the domain.

Proof: Let's put $x=q$ (to see what happens):
$$p^{q-q}=q
$$
$$p^{0}=q\implies q=1\iff x=1
$$

II.

> For the pair $(p;p-1)$ at $x=p\rightarrow p$ can be everything from the domain.

Proof: Let's put $x=p$ (to see what happens):
$$p^{p-q}=p
$$
$$p^{p-q}=p^1\implies p-q=1\implies q=p-1
$$

**Note** that base on the domain:$p\neq1$ that $q\in\mathbb{R}$ **still is true**.